# Can't register code-push

Tags: docker, docker-machine, code-push

I try to check code-push.

I use Cordova into a docker machine into a virtual machine, in Windows.

My problem is that when I try to create an account with "code-push register", I get "A browser is being launched to authenticate your account...". This doesn't help me at all because this runs into a docker machine and no browser can start.
What can I do?

It could help me if I could link a Microsoft account.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands to be able to authenticate against the CodePush service without launching a browser and/or without needing to use your GitHub and/or Microsoft credentials (e.g. in a CI environment),

```
code-push access-key add "VSTS Integration"
```

By default, access keys expire in 60 days. You can specify a different expiry duration by using the --ttl option and passing in a human readable duration string (e.g. "2d" => 2 days, "1h 15 min" => 1 hour and 15 minutes). For security, the key will only be shown once on creation, so remember to save it somewhere if needed!

After creating the new key, you can specify its value using the --accessKey flag of the login command, which allows you to perform "headless" authentication, as opposed to launching a browser.

`code-push login --accessKey <accessKey>`

if at any point you need to change a key's name and/or expiration date, you can use the following command:

```
code-push access-key patch <accessKeyName> --name "new name" --ttl 10d
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. When I use your first code-push command, it raises: "[Error]  You are not currently logged in. Run the 'code-push login' command to authenticate with the CodePush server.". And if I enter 'code-push login', it replies "A browser is being launched to authenticate your account. Follow the instructions it displays to complete your login.". So unless I do something wrong it doesn't work for me.

Comment: First login with the local computer (not the docker) with  ' code-push login' the enter the key that shows up in the browser.
Then from your local computer where you are already logged in ' code-push access-key add "dockerAccess"   ' then you will get the key and you can use ' code-push login --accessKey <accessKey> '  to login from the docker machine. Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thank you. I saw your answer after i posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did the obvious: installed code-push on Windows, performed 'code-push login'. Then the browser opened and after I inserted microsoft login credentials I got the access token to use into Docker.